# How to call web API in WPF 4.0

Tags: asp.net, .net, json, rest, wpf-4.0

I wants to **call web API in my WPF 4.0 application** , where API receive request in JSON format & send response in JSON format.

I got the solution to **call web API in WPF 4.5** from here http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-clients/calling-a-web-api-from-a-wpf-application

but **i want same kind of solution in WPF 4.0**

please help me

Answer (score 2):

you have to install the NuGet package manager and the Http client libraries. This should work: 
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/611176/CallingplusASP-NetplusWebAPIplususingplusHttpClien

Comment: Dear Chevul Ervin , I was tried to install Http client libraries , it was shown error like it requires only .Net 4.5 version .

Comment: Yes you are right, sorry for that, also I did not have time to test this, probably I will do it later but the following link might be the answer: http://johnnycode.com/2012/02/23/consuming-your-own-asp-net-web-api-rest-service/.

Answer (score 0):

```
 public  T CallWebAPi<T>(string userName, string password, Uri url, out bool isSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            T result = default(T);

            using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
            {
                client.BaseAddress = url;
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", Convert.ToBase64String(
                    System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(string.Format("{0}:{1}", userName, password))));

                HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync(url).Result;
                isSuccessStatusCode = response.IsSuccessStatusCode;
                var JavaScriptSerializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
                if (isSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    var dataobj = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                    result = JavaScriptSerializer.Deserialize<T>(dataobj.Result);
                }
                else if (Convert.ToString(response.StatusCode) != "InternalServerError")
                {
                    result = JavaScriptSerializer.Deserialize<T>("{ \"APIMessage\":\"" + response.ReasonPhrase + "\" }");
                }
                else
                {
                    result = JavaScriptSerializer.Deserialize<T>("{ \"APIMessage\":\"InternalServerError\" }");
                }
            }
            return result;
        }
```